# Why is this SUMPRODUCT throwing an error? Structure is okay and the underlying column is error-free

Tags: excel

I'm putting together a `SUMPRODUCT` formula. I know the formula is structured correctly, because if I change the last portion of the formula, it works just fine.

The column `Table1[Milestone Date - Started]` seems to be the issue, but why? It only contains dates, and contains no errors or blanks.

This formula works just fine:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
--(Table1[MS more than 40 days] = "Dead"),
--(MONTH(Table1[Milestone Date - submittal]) = MONTH(Table1[Disb Date for loans that have a Closing Date])),
--(YEAR(Table1[Milestone Date - submittal]) = YEAR(Table1[Disb Date for loans that have a Closing Date])),
--(DAY(Table1[Milestone Date - submittal NW]) = Y$36),
--(Table1[Disbursement Date] >= WORKDAY(EOMONTH(43317, 1), -4)))
```

But this formula throws an error, the only difference is the last line:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
--(Table1[MS more than 40 days] = "Dead"),
--(MONTH(Table1[Milestone Date - submittal]) = MONTH(Table1[Disb Date for loans that have a Closing Date])),
--(YEAR(Table1[Milestone Date - submittal]) = YEAR(Table1[Disb Date for loans that have a Closing Date])),
--(DAY(Table1[Milestone Date - submittal NW]) = Y$36),
--(Table1[Disbursement Date] >= WORKDAY(EOMONTH(Table1[Milestone Date - Started], 1), -4)))
```

Comment: if this is the only change: `WORKDAY(EOMONTH(Table1[Milestone Date - Started], 1), -4)` put that part of the formula in its own cell and see if it works. Is the value in that reference cell actually a date stored in excel date format (ie an integer but displayed as text) or is it a date stored as a string?  you can test it with `=isnumber(Table1[Milestone Date - Started])`

Comment: if your reference date is a range of dates, make sure they are the same size of the other ranges in your sumproduct

Comment: Hi Ed, I put the last line within its own SUMPRODUCT and it throws an error. When I test it with a specific cell within the column, it works fine. The ISNUMBER test returns as TRUE, so it looks like that is okay.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "same size" in your second comment? Thank you for the help!

Comment: lets say your your ranges are A1: A6 for one, C1:C6 and Q3:Q8 then you need to make sure that your milestone Date-started range is also 6 rows long.

Comment: try your workday formula on its own as an array formula not just a regular formula.  IE CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER instead of just ENTER when completing the formula.